# Levels for several variables with for loop (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, levels

I want to see the level as an output of several variables.
Let's say I have 9 variables, and I could do it like this:

```
levels(myd$tel_1)
levels(myd$tel_2)
levels(myd$tel_3)
...
```

But I want to improve it by using a for loop. I think it's useless to use the same function instead of the same code copied underneath.

I've tried something like this:

```
block <-
  c("tel_1",
  "tel_2",
  "tel_3",
  "tel_4",
  "tel_5",
  "tel_6",
  "tel_7",
  "tel_8",
  "tel_9")
  for (j in block) {
    levels(myd[[j]])
  }
```

But this does not work, no error message, nothing. Only the code copied into the console.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Try `lapply(myd[block], levels)`.  Or use `print(levels(myd[[j]]))` in your loop - automatic printing does not occur within a loop.

Comment: it works, thanks. lapply is more convenient as it shows the corresponding variable!